# Capture Key press globally but suppress only for current app and child windows regardless of focus

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I'm running into a weird problem.
I have a WinForms application that opens another program (billing system emulator), sets it as a child window and then disables it. This works fine, the user cannot send any keys to the that child window, and the winforms application does its thing, sending commands to the child window.

However, it's been discovered that pushing the <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>, even if the winforms application doesn't have focus, causes an error in the billing system emulator as they aren't valid keys. Users have taken to not using the <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd> keys while the winforms app runs but that's obviously not a practical solution.

My attempted solution was:

1. Global keyboard hook to capture when those keys are pressed.
2. Overriding `OnKeyDown` in the winforms application to stop those keys.

That however still doesn't solve the problem of the <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> keys being sent to the child window when the winforms app is not in focus. I can stop <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> globally while the winforms app is running but I don't think that is valid. So I need to somehow in the global hook stop the `keypress` for the winforms app and its children but allow globally. Any ideas/thoughts?

This is [my code](http://pastebin.com/r8KF2ejP).

Comment: Rather than tinkering around with globally disabling some keys, why don't you fix the emulator? Or is that impossible (i. e. 3rd party software that's not going to be fixed)?

Comment: It's 3rd party software or that would be my first place to go.

Comment: `I can stop shift and alt globally while the winforms app is running` <-- If you can do this, you can add more conditions to control it, such as do it only when the main app is activated... I don't really get well what you want more?

Comment: BTW, I don't know what `global keyboard hook` lib you are using but when you do it in a native way using `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`, you can set the hook applied to all the threads of the current running module only (that means it's not really global, it's just `module-wide keyboard hook`)

Comment: The child window is receiving the alt and shift keys even when the main app does not have focus. The child window is disabled and no other keys are being sent to it, in or out of focus. Ex: I can start the app and it starts to send commands to the child window, minimize it then open Outlook, create an email and hit shift to capitalize a letter, and when I go back to the minimized main app, maximize it and look at the child window it will have a message that basically states "You can't send shift - invalid key press".

Comment: This is the global keyboard hook class: http://pastebin.com/fAEbXaGh

Comment: How are you sending the keys to the emulator?

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Windows API. We only send the Functions keys and text.

Comment: @KingKing the global hook class I found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook Could you please tell me how to actually set the hook to only apply to my app and its children? Here is what the app and child look like in Process Explorer http://i.imgur.com/IkPpaP2.png

Comment: SendMessage()?...SendInput()?...SomethingElse()?

Comment: @CGross I doubt that your `child window` also has some `global keyboard hook`, that's why even when your main app is not activated, the `shit or alt` key is still captured by the child window.

Comment: @Idle_Mind using SendMesssage. We send both WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP.

Comment: @KingKing Since I can't change anything with the child window being that its a 3rd party application and unlikely to be changed, is there anything I can do at this point?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a good answer for your scenario...  =\

Here's a **hack** you can try.  It will "release" Control/Shift if they are down, then you send your message afterwards:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int extraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern short MapVirtualKey(int wCode, int wMapType);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
        {
            keybd_event((int)Keys.ShiftKey, (byte)MapVirtualKey((int)Keys.ShiftKey, 0), 2, 0); // Shift Up
        }
        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control) 
        {
            keybd_event((int)Keys.ControlKey, (byte)MapVirtualKey((int)Keys.ControlKey, 0), 2, 0); // Control Up
        }

        // ... now try sending your message ...
    }
```

This obviously isn't foolproof.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if that would work as the child window returns "Invalid keypress" as soon as the shift/control is "Down".

Comment: I take it the app doesn't "reset" when those keys are released?  If not, then I think you're stuck with having to suppress them GLOBALLY with a low level keyboard hook.  That's a naughty, naughty app...

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the only constructor of the `globalKeyboardHook` and looks like it is designed only for global hook. You can add another overload to hook into the current running module only like this:

```
class globalKeyboardHook {  
  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
  [DllImport("user32")]
  private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hookType, KeyBoardProc proc, IntPtr moduleHandle, int threadId);
  [DllImport("user32")]
  private static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

  public globalKeyboardHook(bool currentModuleOnly){
     if(currentModuleOnly){
       proc = KeyBoardCallback;
       //WH_KEYBOARD = 0x2
       hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(2, proc, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());       
     } else hook();
  }
  public delegate int KeyBoardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
  public int KeyBoardCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
        if (nCode >= 0) {
            Keys key = (Keys)wParam;
            var lp = lParam.ToInt64();
            //your own handling with the key
            if ((lp >> 31) == 0)//Key down 
            { 
              //your own code ...
            } else { //Key up
              //your own code ...
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  }
  KeyBoardProc proc;
  //other code ...
}
//then use the new overload constructor instead of the parameterless constructor:
globalHook = new globalKeyboardHook(true);
```

**NOTE**: You can implement your own `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` event based on what I posted above (the comment `your own code ...`). After some searching I understand that the `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` supports **global hook** only while the `WH_KEYBOARD` is for `thread hook` only. That should be what you want instead of the `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`.

BTW, I doubt that the `IMessageFilter` which can be registered/added by your application can be used in this case. It also supports a `PreFilterMessage` method helping you to intercept any key and mouse messages at the `application-level`. You should try searching on that, it's easy to follow.

Comment: Thanks. I added that code and its correctly getting the process's module handle but the global shift and control keys are still being captured globally when that app doesn't have focus. I tested it by switching to a Google Doc (and typing) and hitting shift while the winforms app was minimized.

Comment: @CGross see my update, it should be `thread-specific` now but even with that, I'm not sure if it solves your problem (because I'm even not really sure what your problem actually is).